# To validate string or to identify space in a string

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

This is my sample code

```
<setProperty propertyName="selection2">
    <constant>PHONE.NUMBER EQ {phoneNumber}</constant>
</setProperty>
```

How to check whether there is any space in 'phoneNumber' before assigning to PHONE.NUMBER field?

if there is any space I need to replace it with '+' symbol.

Comment: Camel's XML DSL is not my strong area but still this snippet is probably too less for someone else to understand what are you trying to do. Would you mind posting the whole route definition?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an exchange property called `phoneNumber` and you want to replace all spaces with + signs and store the result in another exchange property called `phoneNumberFiltered`, you should be able to use [apache simple](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html) to make a string substitution:

```
<setProperty propertyName="phoneNumberFiltered">
   <simple>${exchangeProperty.phoneNumber.replaceAll(" ", "+")}</simple>
</setProperty>
```